# How can I get the class of a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the code:

```
class Character
{
  void kill();
  void send_to_wall();
}

template <typename T>
void GeorgeFunc(T fp)
{
  ??? obj;
  (obj.*fp)();
}

int main()
{
  GeorgeFunc(&Character::kill);
}
```

So my question here is: how can I get `???`? It seems that the compiler definitely *knows* what this type is (`Character`) during template instantiation, but I'm not sure how to get at it. My current workaround is to change to: `void GeorgeFunc(void (T::*fp)())`, but it would be cleaner to simply get the type from the member function pointer.  `decltype(fp)` would return `void(Character::*)()`, and `decltype(fp())` would return `void`. Any way to get `Character`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, just use a trait to determine this.

```
template <typename> struct member_function_traits;

template <typename Return, typename Object, typename... Args>
struct member_function_traits<Return (Object::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef Return return_type;
    typedef Object instance_type;
    typedef Object & instance_reference;

    // Can mess with Args... if you need to, for example:
    static constexpr size_t argument_count = sizeof...(Args);
};

// If you intend to support const member functions you need another specialization.
template <typename Return, typename Object, typename... Args>
struct member_function_traits<Return (Object::*)(Args...) const>
{
    typedef Return return_type;
    typedef Object instance_type;
    typedef Object const & instance_reference;

    // Can mess with Args... if you need to, for example:
    static constexpr size_t argument_count = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

Now your declaration is:

```
typename member_function_traits<T>::instance_type obj;
```

However, I would argue that since you require a member function pointer (other types would fail to instantiate due to the line `(obj.*fp)()`<sup>1</sup>) that your function *should* take a member function pointer directly instead of a completely generic type.

So this definition would not only work, but I would consider it preferred -- the error messages when someone uses something other than a pointer-to-member-function will be much clearer because the argument type will be incompatible:

```
template <typename Return, typename Object>
void GeorgeFunc(Return (Object::*fp)())
{
    Object obj;
    (obj.*fp)();
}
```

Note that this does allow passing a pointer-to-member-function that returns any type.  Since we don't really use the return value, we don't care what it is.  There is no reason to enforce that it is `void` as in your "workaround."

The only downside to using this approach is that you need two overloads if you intend to also accept pointers to member functions that are declared `const`.  The completely generic implementation does not have this limitation.  (I've long wished that pointers to `const` member functions were implicitly convertible to pointers to non-`const` member functions, but this is currently not allowed by C++.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This isn't 100% true.  If you use a completely generic type as you are right now then the caller could theoretically pass a member *data* pointer instead of a member *function* pointer.  `obj.*fp` would evaluate as a reference to the data member, and then you would be invoking `operator()()` on it.  As long as the data member's type implemented this operator then the template function `GeorgeFunc` could be instantiated.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clean solution and description; there isn't something in the stl already that performs this type of deduction?

Comment: @Rollie Not to my knowledge. I believe boost has such a trait, though.

Comment: That `member_function_traits` will require 24 partial specializations to account for all possibilities (4 possible cv-qualifier-seqs * 3 possible ref-qualifiers * 2 for either varargs or not).  If you just want the class from a pointer-to-member, then simply `template<class T> struct get_class; template<class T, class R> struct get_class<R T::*> { using type = T; };` will suffice and is much shorter (R is deduced to be the appropriate function type if it's a pointer-to-member-function).

Comment: @cdhowie which boost trait is that?

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 one can use deduction guides to determine the class-type and const-ness without much boiler plate:

```
template<bool Const = false, typename R = void, typename C = void, typename... Args> struct MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail
{
    using ClassType = C;
    using ReturnType = R;
    using Arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;
    static constexpr bool isConst = Const;
    //explicit MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(auto){} //C++20 as noticed by duburcqa
    template<typename T> explicit MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(T){}
};
template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args> MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(R(C::**)(Args...)) -> MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail<false, R, C, Args...>;
template<typename R, typename C, typename... Args> MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(R(C::**)(Args...)const) -> MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail<true, R, C, Args...>;

template<typename mfp> using MemberFunctionPointerInfo = decltype(MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail((mfp*){}));
```

You can now use `MemberFunctionPointerInfo<MFPType>::ClassType` as you wish.
Same with ResultType, Arguments (as tuple) and isConst.

The void-default arguments help to prevent compiler-errors if the deduction fails. Basically, `MemberFunctionPointerInfo<int>` will not result in a compilation-error, but the ClassType becoming void. It is possible to static_assert this condition, if a descriptive compiler error is wanted.

Comment: This is C++20 conformant rather than C++17 because "'auto' not allowed in function prototype" (clang compile-time error) related to `explicit MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(auto) {}`.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. GCC only prints a warning in that case and it is not an error. In any case the line in question can be rewritten without loss of functionality: 
`template<typename T> explicit MemberFunctionPointerInfoDetail(T){}`
I have edited my original snippet.